# Async module in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am new in node js. I was learning about async function from async module on github(https://github.com/caolan/async/tree/master/lib). I am using same example as written in parallel.js i.e
var async = require('async');

```
async.parallel({
    one : function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null,1);
        },200);
    },
    two : function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null,2);
        },100);
    }
},function(err,results){
    console.log(results);
});
```

but didn't get the desired output as explained in the documentation i.e {one:1, two:2}. I could't understand why? 
Can anyone make me clearly understand the real concept behind it?

Comment: function must return Promise to work with async module

Comment: thanks for the reply but the official doc didn't mention about any promises to be used and if u refer to this link: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/parallel.js  the first example runs exactly as mentioned but second is not.

Comment: what result did you receive ?

Comment: @Artur - You're just wrong here.  The async module does not use promises at all.  It is an older technology that relies only on plain callbacks.  A more modern approach would not use the async module at all, but would use promises with `Promise.all()`.

Comment: {two:2,one:1} @Fadi Abo Msalam

Answer (score 0):

```
async.parallel({
one : function(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback(null,1);
    },200);
},
two : function(callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback(null,2);
    },100);
  }
 },function(err,results){
console.log(results);
});
```

As you are setting a time of 200 ms and 100 ms respectively.So when the 100ms time is over it executes two and returns 2 then after another 100ms it executes and returns 1 for one .Try changing the values.
Watch this video([how javascript/nodejs works in browser](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=JC5vbignYnV0dG9uJywgJ2NsaWNrJywgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25DbGljaygpIHsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24gdGltZXIoKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ1lvdSBjbGlja2VkIHRoZSBidXR0b24hJyk7ICAgIAogICAgfSwgMjAwMCk7Cn0pOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhpISIpOwoKc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiB0aW1lb3V0KCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkNsaWNrIHRoZSBidXR0b24hIik7Cn0sIDUwMDApOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIldlbGNvbWUgdG8gbG91cGUuIik7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D)).

Comment: ofcourse it is. I also think it should work like as you said. But the official doc says another speech. It says in this case it should return {one:1,two:2} but how???? callback for two is finished earlier and should be displayed first... I had understand the concept of callback but the output in doc create confusion.

Comment: No its not @nilakantha singh deo

Comment: Then may be its a typo in the document.